# Handle flash window event

Tags: c++, windows, qt, winapi

On Windows when parent (main) window is blocked by any modal dialog, clicking on the main window produces dialog flashing. This behaviour is by default for Windows OS. As far as I understand, manually this can be achived with WinApi's [`FlashWindow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-flashwindow) function or Qt's [`QApplication::alert`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#alert).

Is there a way to handle this event in modal dialog? In particular I would like to add some extra actions to dialog. I'm interested in Qt-way solution, but WinApi-way is also appropriated. Trying to handle events via [`QObject::eventFilter`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#eventFilter) gives nothing event when dialog is flashing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the Serhiy Kulish's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53061950/3240681) I used [`nativeEvent`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#nativeEvent) function overload, but for dialog window class (not for the main window):

```
#include <windows.h>

bool MyDialog::nativeEvent(const QByteArray&, void* message, long*)
{
    const auto msg = static_cast<MSG*>(message);

    if (msg->message == WM_NCACTIVATE)
    {
        if (msg->wParam == TRUE) { ... } // dialog become active while blinking
        else { ... } // dialog become inactive while blinking
    }

    return false;
}
```

Window blinking in Windows is implemented as a series of [`WM_NCACTIVATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/wm-ncactivate) messages with `wParam` set to `FALSE` and `TRUE`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to combine [Qwidget::nativeEvent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#nativeEvent) with checking for a modal dialog [QApplication::activeModalWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#activeModalWidget)

For example, check mouse button down in parent of modal window.

```
bool MainWindow::nativeEvent(const QByteArray &eventType, void *message, long *result)
{
   MSG* msg = static_cast<MSG*>(message);
   if (msg->message == WM_SETCURSOR) {
       QWidget* w = qApp->activeModalWidget();
       if (w) {
           WORD mouseMsg = (msg->lParam >> 16);
           if (mouseMsg == WM_LBUTTONDOWN) {
               qDebug() << "Click outside";
           }
       }
   }
   return false;
}
```